# cleanest way to unpack a list in python with type conversions

Tags: python

so python list support is awesome - but there's a situation I run into almost every day - for example:

```py
   for x in re.findall( "..some regex with a bunch of groups..", input ):
       name, height, weight, address, phone = x
       height, weight = int(height), int(weight)
       ... do stuff...
```

I truly love the convenience of being able to unpack a list like this - but it's rare that all the values I want to unpack are the same type - and the extra lines to convert them seem... wrong... somehow

Is there a cleaner way to do this, ideally in a single line?
I know I could do something like:

```py
    name, height, weight, address, phone = (x[0], int(x[1]), int(x[2]), x[3], x[4])
```

but I'm not sure that's cleaner, and it's more open to errors as we have both indices and positions in play.

I guess what I'm looking for is something like

```py
    name, height:int, weight: int, address, phone = x
```

Comment: *`a cleaner way`* is kind of subjective. Why not write a function that takes a sequence as an argument and returns what you want. Inside the function will be all the presumably messy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can think of is the following:

```py
x = ('foo', '1', '2', 'NY', '100')
types = [str, int, int, str, str]

name, height, weight, address, phone = (t(val) for val, t in zip(x, types))
```